# message in web service {"File does not exist."}`

Tags: .net, web-services, iis-7, asmx

I have some web service application , and In it's

```
 protected void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e) {
```

I am getting there  an exception `[System.Web.HttpException] = {"File does not exist."}`
and it's the first place I am stepping in .
How i can get more information about what file is missing ?
The stack is following

```
"   at System.Web.StaticFileHandler.GetFileInfo(String virtualPathWithPathInfo, String physicalPath, HttpResponse response)\r\n   at System.Web.StaticFileHandler.ProcessRequestInternal(HttpContext context)\r\n   at System.Web.DefaultHttpHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext context, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)\r\n   at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()\r\n   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)"
```

Thanks a lot  for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a breakpoint to the application_error method and in the watch window look inside the Server variable. If you look around there are different relative and absolute paths in the different properties like

```
Server 
- Non-Public Members 
   - _context 
      - Request 
         - AppRelativeCurrentExecutionFilePath"
```

Comment: I see there "~/" , but nothing about the absent file name

Comment: Looks to me that that is the problem. It's pointing to a directory and not a file. Looks like you are getting a request 'http://yousrsite/' instead of 'http://yoursite/myservice.asmx'

Comment: So It's related somehow to the users of my application.